# why does my icons not show up when I use a link from CDN

Tags: javascript, html, css, cdn

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.0/css/fontawesome.min.css">
```

```
 <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
```

```
 <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
```

I have copied this cdn link and pasted in my html but the icons still appear as black empty boxes. And yes i have already classed them as fa aswell can someone please help.

I want it to display an X and a menu button but something doesnt make it display on my screen.

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors. The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** tab. Inspect your elements. What do the applied CSS rules reveal? The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested? Amend the URL accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your link isn't working well.

If you check the resource, following sebastian simon advice, response is HTTP 200, so loading is ok.

But yes you have rectangular box.

Try

```css
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">
```

I've tested yours: black box.

With this CDN: everything works well